# Hibernate long session

Tags: hibernate

In my app i'm going to use only one very long Hibernate session. Why am i going to use that? There will be mainly inserts to database - SQLite, around 10 in 1 seconds, and some reads every few hours. So here comes my question, do i need to care about closing and starting a new session from time to time (for cashing purpose), or hibernate will manage it itself? or any other tips or links regarding long sessions in hibernate.
Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, that's not a good idea. Take care to always use a new session.

Comment: even if a method that persist is called 10 times per second? there will be 10 session creations per second...

Comment: Yes. Some systems achieve millions of transactions per second.